# tf.train.range_input_producer(epoch_size, shuffle=True) does not terminate nor induce CPU/GPU load

Tags: python, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network, word-embedding

I've got a strange issue while working on RNN. I am following [TensorFlow RNN Tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/tutorials/recurrent/index.html#recurrent-neural-networks) and trying my own (simpler) implementation which is quite inspired by [R2RT's Blog Post: Recurrent Neural Networks in Tensorflow I](http://r2rt.com/recurrent-neural-networks-in-tensorflow-i.html) .

After debugging I indentified the problem was coming from the `ranger_input_producer` in [tensorflow.models.rnn.ptb.reader.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/models/rnn/ptb/reader.py) (line. 115).

I isolated it in the smallest example:

```
import tensorflow as tf

epoch_size = 20
i = tf.train.range_input_producer(epoch_size, shuffle=False).dequeue()
```

Which is what `ptb_producer` (with variable value for `epoch_size`).
In turns out that this code, as is, does not terminate (I don't even call any `session.run(...)` nor use CPU. I guess that the queue is waiting something as [suggested by Daving Wong](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40407781/5903959).

Any clues?
Thx

pltrdy

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you just use code of 
`with tf.Session() as sess:`,
you must open the thread explicitly with 
`threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners()`. 
But in ptb_word_lm.py, It uses the codes like this 
`sv = tf.train.Supervisor()  with sv.managed_session() as sess:`,
the Supervisor() function contains something which starts the thread implicitly

Comment: For various reasons I did used an iterator instead of queues (as in tensorflow 0.11 ptb_word_lm implementation). 
Still, I do think that you are right, as I read stuff related to "manually" start queues etc. Thus I'm validating this anwser. Thx :)

Answer (score 0):

You might be hitting a dequeue I/O block due to an empty queue. (ptb_producer uses tf.train.range_input_producer, which uses a FIFOQueue.)  According to [documentation](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/data_flow_ops.py#L400) the queue will block until there's an element to return.  Please double check your directory and data.

Comment: You're right in that the problem must come from the I/O since even `sess.run(data)` does not terminate. Btw, directory/file are ok (otherwise it raise an exception. Don't see real differences on the way I handle data.